# Problem looping over multiple divs using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Below is my python code for scraping using BS4. When I try to run the loop it prints the same data and also please let me know how to run the pagination loop in python.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/restaurants'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(page.content,'html.parser')
#print(len(soup))

containers = soup.find_all("div",{"class","v-card"})
#print(containers[0])

name = containers.find_all("a",{"class","business-name"})
print(name[0].get_text())

phone = soup.find_all("div",{"class","phone"})
#print(phone[0].get_text())

add = soup.find_all("p",{"class","adr"})
#print(add[0].get_text())


for items in containers: 
    name_soup = containers.find("a",{"class","business-name"})
    print(name_soup)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and think of a better title. Also format the code properly: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: That title is going to get you a lot of downvotes. Why not write one that describes your actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will give you an error-

```
name = containers.find_all("a",{"class","business-name"})
```

because *containers* is a list, and not a single element on which you could call *find_all()* method.

You need to access *containers* in a loop, as it is a list of *div* tags that you have extracted on the previous line.

This is your previous line, where you are extracting all *div* tags (having class=v-card) in a list-

```
containers = soup.find_all("div",{"class","v-card"})
```

Comment: I have changed it but still the loop does not work.

Comment: what's the error? did you try what @Jonathon Reinhart suggested?

Comment: Check this:  there is a <a> tag and in this tag it contains <span> tag. I need to print the span tag. Please check this screenshot: prnt.sc/s4n64w

Comment: In the loop, *item.find("a",{"class","business-name"})* will give you a single <a> tag. You can check for <span> tag inside it using  *name_soup.span* . To print text inside the span tag, you could use *getText()* method on it.

Comment: As I am beginner in python, I am not able to run this.

Comment: How can I write the data from python to CSV file?

Comment: You can use pandas.DataFrame to store data and then write it to csv. Check out this article on DataFrame - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

```
for items in containers: 
    name_soup = containers.find("a",{"class","business-name"})
    print(name_soup)
```

You're not using your `items` variable; you're constantly searching in `containers`.

Use `items.find(...)`.

> please let me know how to run the pagination loop in python.

This is much more broad and really depends on the target website. Look at what changes when you click the (next page) button on the site. Often it's just a query string parameter (e.g. `?p=3`). Then replicate that in your GET.

Comment: It show me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bs.py", line 14, in <module>
    name = containers.find_all("a",{"class","business-name"})
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2127, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Looking more, your loop makes no sense. Why are you trying to find the same div inside of a collection of divs? You need to show a minimal example of the HTML.

Comment: because there is a <a> tag and in this tag it contains <span> tag. I need to print the span tag.

Please check this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/s4n64w